# Case-based query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a employee table as follows:

```
    ID|description|Grade I|Grade II|
    1|Permanent   |       |T       |
    2|Temp        |T      |        |
    3|Permanent   |       |        |
```

The Grade columns qualify 'excellent' or 'good';depending upon which of the above columns is not null.
I need to write a query which gives the following output:

```
 ID|description
    1|Permanent(Excellent)
    2|Temp(Good)
    3|Permanent
```

I am on Sql Server 2008.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: As with everything on StackOverflow ... what have you tried?

Comment: You can use a function or case statements in a select to return the Description for you, but like Rob said. What have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
SELECT ID,Description,
       CASE WHEN GRADE1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Excellent'
            WHEN GRADE2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Good'
            WHEN GRADE1 IS NULL AND GRADE2 IS NULL THEN 'AVERAGE'
            ELSE ' '
       END [GRADE]
FROM TABLE1
```

Please take a look at

## [CASE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx&ei=zHXrUqLiBsruyQGGk4HICQ&usg=AFQjCNH1gfmVoRmtc7MehHOPswZt9-RYpQ&bvm=bv.60444564,d.aWc)

Answer (score 1):

```
 create table #employee (ID INT,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(20),GradeI varchar(20),GradeII VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO #employee VALUES(1,'Permanent',NULL,'T')
 INSERT INTO #employee VALUES(2,'Temp','T',NULL)
 INSERT INTO #employee VALUES(3,'Permanent',NULL,NULL)

SELECT id ,DESCRIPTION,CASE WHEN GradeI IS NOT NULL THEN 'GOOD' 
                       ELSE CASE WHEN GradeII IS NOT NULL THEN 'Excellent' 
                       ELSE '' END 
                       END
FROM #employee
```